# Prove solution is stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Prove that the trivial solution of
>   $$2x'' + x^3 + x\sqrt{x^4 + 4(x')^2}=0$$
>   is stable.

I tried many Liapunov functions but none of them are giving me the result I want. For example, $V(x,y)=(x^4 + 4y^2)^{3/2}$ $(y = x')$ did not work. What should I try next?

Comment: $x = \sin(t)$ is a solution, as well as $x = \cos(t)$

Comment: I didn't believe it until I checked. How the hell did you come up with that?

Comment: Being more precise, $\{\epsilon\sin(\epsilon t), \epsilon\cos(\epsilon t)\}$ are also solutions.

Comment: You don't have to take $y=x'$. Try to choose $y=cx'$ for some $c>0$. The stability doesn't change!